# Rogue Database Appears in MySQL Show Databases

Tags: mysql, database

I see today that

```
show databases
```

displays an unknown database:

```
(msl_ampcs_v4_0_0_2g)> show databases;
+----------------------+
| Database             |
+----------------------+
| information_schema   |
| #mysql50#.ssh        |
| global_lad
```

Normally when I see something like that it is due to a bad file in /var/lib/mysql:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql       1663 Mar 17  2011 /var/lib/mysql/ca-cert.pem
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql       4096 Jun 18 15:00 /var/lib/mysql/global_lad
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql       4096 Jun 18 15:00 /var/lib/mysql/global_lad_unit_test
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql 3231711232 Aug 22 07:20 /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql    5242880 Aug 22 07:20 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile0
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql    5242880 Aug 21 16:25 /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile1
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql          5 Feb 21  2013 /var/lib/mysql/istsdb2.jpl.nasa.gov.pid
-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql    4596466 Oct 15  2010 /var/lib/mysql/istsdb2-slow.log
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql       4096 Jul 13  2011 /var/lib/mysql/msl_ampcs_v2_0_0
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql       4096 Jul 21  2012 /var/lib/mysql/msl_ampcs_v3_0_0
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql       4096 Jun 20 02:55 /var/lib/mysql/msl_ampcs_v4_0_0
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql       4096 Sep  5 19:45 /var/lib/mysql/msl_ampcs_v4_0_0_2g
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql       4096 Sep 30  2010 /var/lib/mysql/msl_gdsdb_v5_0
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql       4096 Jan 19  2011 /var/lib/mysql/msl_gdsdb_v5_5
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql       4096 Nov 21  2011 /var/lib/mysql/msl_gdsdb_v5_6
drwx------ 2 mysql root        4096 Mar 23  2010 /var/lib/mysql/mysql
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql          0 Feb 21  2013 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
-rw------- 1 root  root         841 Jun 10  2010 /var/lib/mysql/nohup.out
drwx------ 2 mysql mysql       4096 Feb  5  2013 /var/lib/mysql/pdpp_automation
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql       1310 Mar 17  2011 /var/lib/mysql/server-cert.pem
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql       1679 Mar 17  2011 /var/lib/mysql/server-key.pem
```

But nothing like that is present. The nohup shouldn't be there. But

```
#mysql50#.ssh
```

does not appear.

Comment: You should not `normally` face these situations. Besides, why are you executing nohup with root privileges in `/var/lib/mysql`? That script is breaking something. What is the output of `ls -lA` ?

Comment: Did you upgrade your MySQL instance recently? Others have reported issues with tables with hashes [1](http://g33kinfo.com/info/archives/5080) [2](http://mattiasgeniar.be/2010/08/07/mysql-upgrade-to-5-1-database-name-prefix-mysql50/) [3](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-database.html)

Comment: ls -lA showed a .ssh directory under /var/lib/mysql, along with .bash_history and others. That is caused by the mysql account having its home directory on /var/lib/mysql. Removing the .ssh directory solved the problem. The nohup was caused by root being cereless, I guess.

Comment: Oh, and thanks! The SA set up the mysql account. I presume he should have put the home directory elsewhere? Or should we not use the mysql account at all and leave it to mysql itself?